# Temperature dependence of the Higgs VEV

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, big-bang, phase-transition, higgs

Presumably, The Higgs field vacuum expectation value has a strong temperature dependence close to the electroweak symmetry breaking phase transition. Does this have known consequences for the development of the very early universe?

Comment: There's an enormous amount of literature on this topic. Here's an early (and heavily cited) paper by Weinberg which may help get you started: https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.9.3357