# Is the analytical dependence of the theoretical Higgs potential with temperature known?

Tags: temperature, standard-model, higgs, symmetry-breaking

At the very beginning of the unvierse, the Higgs potential had a paraboloid shape.
After the electroweak Symmetry Breaking, it took the mexican hat shape.

Is the analytical dependence of Higgs potential with temperature known ?

Comment: Related: [Temperature dependence of the Higgs VEV](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509489/)

Comment: Thank you, but the vev is a consequence of the potential, so my question is different. And also, the answer to the other link needs to pay for accessing the document.

Comment: That paper behind the paywall is the original 1974 Weinberg paper that Simon’s answer mentions. It calculates the temperature corrections to the potential, not just the vev.

Comment: @G. Smith : thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formalism used to describe the temperature dependence of the Higgs VEV is called a *finite temperature effective potential* (FTEP).

The temperature contribution to the effective potential was calculated by Weinberg and by Jackiw & Dolan independently in 1974. The FTEP at one-loop order and at high temperature ($T\gg T_c$) looks like
$$
V_{\mathrm{T}}(\phi_{\mathrm{cl}})= V_{\mathrm{eff}}(\phi_{\mathrm{cl}}) + \frac{\lambda}{8}T^2\phi_{\mathrm{cl}}^2 - \frac{\pi^2}{90}T^4 + \cdots
$$
where $V_{\mathrm{eff}}(\phi_{\mathrm{cl}})$ is the zero-temperature one-loop effective potential (which will have the Mexican hat shape). This means that the additional $ \phi_{\mathrm{cl}}^2$ term due to the temperature contribution will dominate over the original $ \phi_{\mathrm{cl}}^2$ term due to the "mass term" in the Higgs potential. Here is a plot of the FTEP temperature dependence:
[image]
Note that the expression above is only valid for high temperatures, so plotting out that potential will not produce the same figure.

Comment: A million thanks for your answer

Comment: Hello. Would you have the reference for the picture ? and for the equation ? Thank you

Comment: I made the picture myself. Similar pictures and the equations that generate them can be found in the textbook "The Early Universe" by Kolb and Turner and in this review article: https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.2942

Comment: Thank you for the informations