# When Higgs mechanism occurred ? Or it occurs everytime?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, standard-model, higgs, electroweak

I’m studying SSB and the Higgs mechanism, and I’m having a few doubts about when Higgs mechanism occurred. From my knowledge, all particles were created massless, and they gain mass after SSB. What I don’t get is, when that happened? Is something that happened in the early universe, and after that every particles were massive, or it happens all the time (like if when a particle is created, it’s massless, but interact with Higgs field and acquire mass)?

At the moment I picture the scenario in which particles gain mass in this way: at some time during the evolution of the universe, the Higgs field gained a non zero vacuum expectation value. From that time, every time a particle is created, it’s massless, and immediately interact with Higgs field to gain a mass.

Before that time, particles would still interact with Higgs field, but since the acquired mass depends on Higgs vev(which would be zero), they won’t gain mass.

Comment: Your "all particles were created massless, and they gain mass after SSB" framing conjures up a strange creator turning on an SSB dial, which does not happen. All free particles have their SSB-specified masses as they are created and destroyed. "After SSB" is a shared metaphor you are misusing.

Comment: In my mind I think of creation of particles as due to some physical process( pair creation and annihilation for example) rather than some creator.

Comment: Pair creation occurs within SSB. What's this "before SSB"?

Comment: I thought SSB occurred some time during the evolution of the universe. Before SSB would mean before that time.

Comment: SSB is a property of the vacuum but may be rescinded at high temperatures. Nothing to do with the history of the universe, except that it happened to cool down. You input its temperature evolution to describe it, not  the nature of SSB, which is actually applied to refine this description. SSB is independent of time, in the abstract.

Comment: Oh ok, and is it correct to say that at lower temperatures SSB can happen(as a consequence)? And that the consequence of SSB happening is that the Higgs field gained a vev different from zero?

Comment: I guess you could, but it is important to *not* put the cart before the horse. SSB is always present, but may be obscured/overridden by a high-T medium. It so happened that the early universe had that high T feature; but in a fanciful universe with oscillating T (just an argument fantasy) you'd have oscillating SSB-or-none. There is no time historicity involved in a law of nature.

Comment: Yes I understand your remark about SSB being always present. And in all of this, the vev of the Higgs field was always different from zero?

Comment: Basically yes, *but*, at *cosmologically high* T you may describe  things by an effective theory where the vev is insignificant ~ zero. Today, however, it is a terrible idea to visualize anything at all with a vanishing vev (unless you are confident you know what you are doing).

Comment: Ok, so we can say that at cosmological high temperature particles are massless since SSB is "obscured"?

Comment: Yes. [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/555513/is-the-analytical-dependence-of-the-theoretical-higgs-potential-with-temperature). You must clarify in your question which regime you are talking about and skip the cosmology.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your help, your patience and the link.